# Inequality for a determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant, positive-definite

Let $A=(a_{i,j})$ an $n\times n$ symmetric definite positive matrix i.e. for all $n\times1$ vector $x\ne0$ we have
$$x^T A x>0.$$
We write the matrix $A$ by blocks:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}A_1 &y^T\\
y& a_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}$$
and the question is to prove that $\det(A)\le a_{n,n}\det(A_1)$. Honestly I have no idea how to get this inequality but at least I have proved that $a_{n,n}>0$ and in fact $a_{i,i}>0$ for all $i$.

Comment: The obvious tool to attempt here would seem to be the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). If you haven't seen it before, focus on the block-Gaussian elimination tools presented there.

Comment: @Semiclassical Schur complement is interesting and surely we can get the inequality within this tool but the question is for undegraduate linear algebra students with only the very basic and classical tools.

Comment: Well, the basic tool is just block-Gaussian elimination. For instance, $$\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} I & 0 \\ -D^{-1}C & I\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} A-BD^{-1}C & B \\ 0 & D\end{pmatrix}.$$ Another block-multiplication on the left is enough to remove $B$. This isn't to say that the problem can be done without invoking these ideas, but it seems clear that such concepts is what the problem is secretly founded on.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is real symmetric PD.  Running Cholesky Factorization:
$A=LL^T$ which we partition as
$L=\begin{pmatrix}L_1 &0\\
\mathbf m^T& l_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}A_1 &\mathbf y\\
\mathbf y^T& a_{n,n}\end{pmatrix} =LL^T=\begin{pmatrix}L_1 &0\\
\mathbf m^T& l_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}L_1^T &\mathbf m\\
0& l_{n,n}\end{pmatrix}$
$\implies A_1 =L_1L_1^T$
$\implies a_{n,n} =\mathbf m^T\mathbf m +l_{n,n}^2\geq l_{n,n}^2\gt 0$
using the multiplicativity of determinants and the fact that the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of its diagonals, we have

$\det\big(A\big)$
$=\det\big(L\big)\det\big(L^T\big)$
$=\det\big(L^2\big)$
$=\big(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}l_{k,k}^2\big)\cdot l_{n,n}^2$
$=\det\big(L_1^2\big)\cdot l_{n,n}^2$
$\leq \det\big(L_1\big)^2\cdot a_{n,n}$
$= \det\big(L_1L_1^T\big)\cdot a_{n,n}$
$=\det\big(A_1\big)\cdot a_{n,n}$